# Is 'how very wrong he was' correct?

Tags: adverbs

I see this sentence in Harry Potter. My understanding is that 'how' here works as an adverb and very is an adverb too. So, I am not sure if it is correct to put them together here. For example, how silly you are. Can we say *how very silly you are*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How very silly you are!** is an *exclamatory sentence* that is *exclamatory in form*. This simply means that the sentence starts with **What** or **How**, and the object of the sentence is placed before the subject and main verb. And, of course, an exclamation point is used.

A few examples:

> You have pretty eyes. => What pretty eyes you have!
>
> She is beautiful. => How beautiful she is!
>
> It is droll. => How droll!

There is an excellent explanation of exclamatory sentences here:
https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/exclamatory-sentence.html

Comment: Does *how very wrong* or *how very silly* sound correct to you?

Comment: Yes, they are grammatical and sound fine. Not all native speakers speak this way. If you use this kind of sentence too much, people might think you're being cutesy or melodramatic.